# How to add table of contents in HTML output of knit /Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

What are possible ways of adding table of contents in html output of `knitr::knit2html()`?

I am familiar with the `markdownHTMLOptions` solution. However the result is not the good-looking one? For me it is important to have such table of contents so that it follows the webpage while scrolling and i could possibly navigate anytime I want.

Comment: You may generate the TOC dynamically with e.g. `jQuery` by selecting all the `h1`, `h2` etc. tags and adding a link to that element in a custom `div` that might be also with `position:absolute` style.

Answer (score 6):

A floating table of contents is now supported by Rmarkdown! It moves with you as you scroll, you click to navigate... such an improvement :)

The directions are very good: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html

In short, add this at the top of your rmd script, where toc stands for table of contents, and float means that it stays visible on the left as the page scrolls:

```
---
title: "Bla"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
---
```

Comment: Answers on StackOverflow should actually contain an answer, not just the directions towards the answer.  Can you expand on the advice? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thank you @MikeyHarper I edited my answer to reflect your advice.